# No SSH link in Gitblit (installed in tomcat ROOT directory)

Tags: git, tomcat, ssh, xampp, gitblit

I have installed Gitblit in tomcat root directory but SSH link is not visible. It can be solved by moving gitblit out tomcat ROOT directory. But I need gitblit in that directory because of some network and firewall issue. I am using giblit in tomcat (XAMPP) on windows server 2012 R2.